# Slidemenu get element onclick

Tags: android, menu, gradle, slide

Hi I am new for android developer. I am using this [library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) adding sliding menu to my application.
However how can i fire onlick listener? Please see my code below

Activitymain.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >




        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnMenuFrame"

            >


            <Button
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"

                android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/menu">

            </Button>


        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnUserProfile"

            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_1_b"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnTree"

            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_2_b"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnManage"

            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_3_b"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            />





    </LinearLayout>







    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblCelcius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="Arial"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="80sp"

            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblCity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="Arial"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wetherLinear"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgWether"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblWetherMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                android:fontFamily="Arial"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

SlidingMenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/slidemenu"
    android:background="#f8f3ef">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#9B1B32"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnMenuFrame">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"

                android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/menu">

            </Button>


        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu"
                android:textColor="#9B1B32"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowUserProfile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowUserProfileDetail"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/etree"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblUserEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/etree"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

     </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSeperator1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowUserProfile"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowEtree"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowUserProfile"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_etree" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/etree"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSeperator3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowEtree"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowRecruit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSeperator3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_recruit" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/recruit"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSeperator4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowRecruit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowNetwork"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSeperator4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_network" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/network"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSeperator5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowNetwork"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowReward"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSeperator5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_reward" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/reward"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSeperator6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowReward"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RowWallet"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSeperator6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_wallet" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wallet"
            android:textColor="#9B1B32"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSeperator7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RowReward"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/line"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Activitymain);
// configure the SlidingMenu
        final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);

        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.slidemenu);

}
```

Any solution? If yes . Please provide me a simple example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the example on the github repository. Handle item clicks in *onOptionsItemSelected*.